# how do I add a column with type array using phpMyAdmin or sql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

how do I add a column with type array using phpMyAdmin
knowing that
alter table name add column listid integer array;
alter table name add column listid integer [];
not working

Comment: Maybe is not working because array data type doesn't exist in MySql

Comment: Rather than the uninformative not working statement you should add the error message in full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, an array is not a type. You could opt to instead have a separate table which keeps the elements in the array, and let them have a foreign key referring to the original table, or parse the array into a String each time and store it as text, depending on your needs.

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  description TEXT,
  reference TEXT
  -- This is where you'd want to add your list of order lines
);

-- Instead, we'll create an orderline table referring back to the orders
CREATE TABLE orderlines (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  description TEXT,
  order_id INT REFERENCES orders(id)
);
```

Now you can put your array values (which I now assume to be the order lines) in their own separate table. To query them, you could do

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders
LEFT JOIN orderlines ON orderlines.order_id = orders.id;
```

Which you could probably make smart enough using sub-queries to return you an array, especially within your application.

Comment: Or possibly JSON..

Comment: Oh good point! You can actually  store a JSON array as well OP. For simple objects that's probably easier. If they get more complex, you'll likely benefit from putting them in a separate database table, though. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html